# Effective way to get unused rowid in Android/SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

Suppose you do not want to recycle rowids for for table myTable below.

For that you define:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,
  <Other columns>
)
```

Then you want to get next unused rowid in android/SQLite environment.

How will you do that efficiently?

Perhaps we need object
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
and perhaps(?) object
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement

but what is most efficient way to do this task?

Note: 
I do not want to create row into myTable.
But of course you can create row and delete it 
if that is the best way to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the current value of that sequence from the [sqlite_sequence table](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#seqtab).

Answer (score 1):

As you identified, creating a row and deleting it is a valid approach. The other way would be to run a

```
SELECT id FROM myTable ORDER BY id DESC
```

Then look at the id of the first row returned and increment it by one. Be careful of concurrency though. If you insert something immediately after checking for an unused row than you might get some unexpected behavior.

**Edit:** Check out CL.'s answer. It's more practical. Plus you could update manually increment that table's sequence number so that you are guaranteed your row will be unused.

Answer (score 0):

I've never understood why someone would need to do this, but it can be done:

[The SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) mentions that the auto_increment values are stored in a `sqlite_sequence` table which is created automatically in your database when you use auto_increments.

[This S.O. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107005/predict-next-auto-inserted-row-id-sqlite#answer-5301923) explains one way to query the `sqlite_sequence` table to find the current maximum ID, you could then add 1 to it and 99.9% of the time this would be the next ID issued.

Comment: That table contains last used id.
Then I must update by one and then select to that table
for this simple important task???

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is something like:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE sqlite_sequence set seq=seq+1 WHERE name='myTable'");

SQLiteStatement st = db.compileStatement("SELECT seq from sqlite_sequence WHERE name='myTable'");
long v = st.simpleQueryForLong();
st.close();
```

Now v is unused rowid which anyone other will not get.
Perhaps these statements must be in same transaction.

Not so simple for simple and quite common task?

Comment: The simple and quite common task would be just inserting a new record. Why don't you want to do that?

Comment: Once again:
I do not want insert record into table at a same moment
when I need id but I must be sure that id is reserved for me.
So insert does not work. Insert+delete works but not so nice.

Comment: A warning from the SQLite manual:
"Making modifications to this table will likely perturb the AUTOINCREMENT key generation algorithm. Make sure you know what you are doing before you undertake such changes."

You should also bare in mind that AUTOINCREMENT rows will not *always* be the exact next number. Some conditions may cause the autoincrement value to provide a number that is a) more than 1 greater than the current value or b) another row id that was previously deleted.

I would insert a blank row to reserve an ID, and then populate the missing data with an UPDATE later.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `SQLiteOpenHelper` you use, start a transaction. Insert some data and then rollback.

Such a way, you 'll be able to get the next row id, like this:

```
public long nextId() {
    long rowId = -1;

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        // fill values ...

        // insert a valid row into your table
        rowId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        // NOTE: we don't call  db.setTransactionSuccessful()
        // so as to rollback and cancel the last changes
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
    return rowId;
}
```