# How to store database value in variable

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this query which I want to check if its null or have some value and if have that value I want to store it in variable

```
max_id = db.exec(SELECT max(campaign_id)as campaign_id FROM campaign_main);
```

So i want something like this

```
if (db != null)
campaign_id = max_id + 1;
else
campaign_id = 1;
```

Comment: Why don't you use an [autoincrementing ID](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)?

Comment: Better use that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107005/predict-next-auto-inserted-row-id-sqlite

Comment: search about this. this can be achieved using SQL only. Not sure how, but m sure it can be done.

Comment: ok you mean something like this INSERT into tablename (SELECT max(id) + 1)

Comment: Actually i cant use autoincrement as at the same time i m populating the other table to with the foreign_key with the first table primary_key

Comment: Do you have circular references? If not, just insert the parent first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
String sql = "SELECT max(campaign_id) FROM campaign_main";
long max_id = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, sql, null);
if (max_id < 0)
    max_id = 0;
campaign_id = max_id + 1;
```

You can also do the logic in SQL:

```java
String sql = "SELECT ifnull(max(campaign_id), 0) + 1 FROM campaign_main";
long campaign_id = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, sql, null);
```